# OpenVPN 3 client on iOS connects, but fails to send data, "unknown IP version"

Tags: ios, openvpn

I've got a build of the OpenVPN3 client library (https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3) connecting to an OpenVPN 2 server (2.4.4). This is working for my mac and windows builds, but failing when the client is iOS.

The iOS client appears to connect, in the sense that I get my custom up script invoked and I can see what I assume are keepalive/heartbeat packets going back and forth between client and server. The client doesn't time out as long as these packets are allowed to continue. However, as soon as the client attempts to access any web page over the tunnel, I get packets dropped on the server side with errors like the following:

```
Fri Mar 15 20:08:27 2019 11e9-475e-04b1a640-b6f1-dda173e0051f/10.101.172.10:65334 IP packet with unknown IP version=10 seenFri Mar 15 20:08:28 2019 11e9-475e-04b1a640-b6f1-dda173e0051f/10.101.172.10:65334 IP packet with unknown IP version=7 seen
Fri Mar 15 20:08:29 2019 11e9-475e-04b1a640-b6f1-dda173e0051f/10.101.172.10:65334 IP packet with unknown IP version=5 seen
Fri Mar 15 20:08:30 2019 11e9-475e-04b1a640-b6f1-dda173e0051f/10.101.172.10:65334 IP packet with unknown IP version=9 seen
Fri Mar 15 20:08:31 2019 11e9-475e-04b1a640-b6f1-dda173e0051f/10.101.172.10:65334 IP packet with unknown IP version=8 seen
Fri Mar 15 20:08:32 2019 11e9-475e-04b1a640-b6f1-dda173e0051f/10.101.172.10:65334 IP packet with unknown IP version=2 seen
Fri Mar 15 20:08:34 2019 11e9-475e-04b1a640-b6f1-dda173e0051f/10.101.172.10:65334 IP packet with unknown IP version=13 seen
Fri Mar 15 20:08:38 2019 11e9-475e-04b1a640-b6f1-dda173e0051f/10.101.172.10:65334 IP packet with unknown IP version=7 seen
```

I'm using the same server and client configs for iOS as I was using when the client was Mac and Windows.

Server configs:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca /opt/certs/ca-cert.pem
cert /opt/certs/server.pem
key /opt/certs/server-key.pem
dh /opt/certs/dh2048.pem
tls-auth /opt/certs/ta.key 0

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
keepalive 5 15

verb 3
script-security 3
client-connect "/usr/local/bin/sdp-updown"
client-disconnect "/usr/local/bin/sdp-updown"
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256
comp-lzo
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
```

Client configs:

```
dev tun
proto udp
remote ... server and port omitted
remote-cert-tls server
key-direction 1
server-poll-timeout 5
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256
comp-lzo
... routes omitted
<ca>
... CA omitted
</ca>
<cert>
... cert omitted
</cert>
<key>
... private key omitted
</key>
<tls-auth>
... OpenVPN static key omitted
</tls-auth>
```

I've tried a number of different settings for `cipher` and `tls-cipher`. When those settings are set to values that are supported on both sides I can get connected, but get the same `IP packet with unknown IP version` error. Obviously when either `cipher` or `tls-cipher` isn't supported on either server or client we fail to negotiate TLS and don't get connected at all.

I found a number of troubleshooting forum posts regarding this error and most of them are resolved by setting the compression settings to the same value on both ends. My iOS client build seems to think that it has no ability to perform compression, even though I think I've linked successfully against the LZ4 library. I compiled the LZ4 library for iOS, and included the `LZ4=1` when building a `dylib` for OpenVPN itself. However, when the iOS client connects it reports settings like:

```
ENV[IV_AUTO_SESS] = 1
ENV[IV_COMP_STUBv2] = 1
ENV[IV_COMP_STUB] = 1
ENV[IV_LZO_STUB] = 1
ENV[IV_PROTO] = 2
ENV[IV_TCPNL] = 1
ENV[IV_NCP] = 2
ENV[IV_PLAT] = ios
ENV[IV_VER] = 3.1.2
```

I notice that this does not include `IV_LZ4`, which I take to mean that the client thinks it can't perform compression. That said, even when my configs include disabled compression I get the same results. I tried omitting any compression setting at all, `comp-lzo no`, `compress stub`, and `compress stub-v2`. None of these resulted in any different behavior.

My questions are thus:

1. What could be the cause of my `IP packet with unknown IP version` errors when actually sending packets over the data channel?
2. If what I'm seeing is actually a compression setting error, how do I convince OpenVPN to disable compression entirely? Alternatively, what have I done wrong to link LZ4 into my iOS OpenVPN dylib?